# GNU parallel - running with proxy host

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, administration

I've been recently dealing with GNU parallel and parallel computation. I have two machines available, one where I work and one behind a proxy machine, so I work at A, I can access C only via B and I can not compute on B.

My question is, how do I create the hosts file for GNU parallel to understand I want to share files with machine C? I have enabled password-less logins to both B and C from B.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Using-remote-computers-behind-NAT-wall

**EXAMPLE: Using remote computers behind NAT wall**

If the workers are behind a NAT wall, you need some trickery to get to them.

If you can ssh to a jump host, and reach the workers from there, then the obvious solution would be this, but it does not work:

```
parallel --ssh 'ssh jumphost ssh' -S host1 echo ::: DOES NOT WORK
```

It does not work because the command is dequoted by ssh twice where as GNU parallel only expects it to be dequoted once.

So instead put this in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host host1 host2 host3
  ProxyCommand ssh jumphost.domain nc -w 1 %h 22
```

It requires nc(netcat) to be installed on jumphost. With this you can simply:

```
parallel -S host1,host2,host3 echo ::: This does work
```

**No jumphost, but port forwards**

If there is no jumphost but each server has port 22 forwarded from the firewall (e.g. the firewall's port 22001 = port 22 on host1, 22002 = host2, 22003 = host3) then you can use ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host host1.v
    Port 22001
Host host2.v
    Port 22002
Host host3.v
    Port 22003
Host *.v
    Hostname firewall
```

And then use host{1..3}.v as normal hosts:

```
parallel -S host1.v,host2.v,host3.v echo ::: a b c
```

**No jumphost, no port forwards**

If ports cannot be forwarded, you need some sort of VPN to traverse the NAT-wall. TOR is one options for that, as it is very easy to get working.

You need to install TOR and setup a hidden service. In torrc put:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

Then start TOR: /etc/init.d/tor restart

The TOR hostname is now in /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname and is something similar to izjafdceobowklhz.onion. Now you simply prepend torsocks to ssh:

```
parallel --ssh 'torsocks ssh' -S izjafdceobowklhz.onion \
    -S zfcdaeiojoklbwhz.onion,auclucjzobowklhi.onion echo ::: a b c
```

If not all hosts are accessible through TOR:

```
parallel -S 'torsocks ssh izjafdceobowklhz.onion,host2,host3' echo ::: a b c
```